# Trying to focus and select a telerick textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, telerik-mvc

Hey I am having an issue with a telerick control that is seriously bugging me. All I want to do is select a textbox and focus on it. I understand telerick has different controls etc but I find it crazy that modern techs like jquery etc cannot select it.

Anyway rant over does anyone know how I would select a textbox and focus on it? I can find the element no problem it's just the after part as .focus() does not work

Answer (score 0):

So just doing a clean up of old questions and saw this hanging around from when I first started with telerick.

The problem was actually in how telerick elements work. Basically be careful with telerick controls as the "edit" textbox for example is actually a new dynamically created textbox in front of the original. So this was the issue I had but also look out for how telerick names elements on render.